# System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.IO.IOException: The file exists

Tags: c#, .net

We are running jobs on our application server and the jobs were running fine early in the  morning and then in the afternoon they started failing with this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compile both on .NET 4.5 and on .NET 4.0. 4.5 Exception: System.IO.IOException: The file exists

When Googling I find the error only once and it is dealing with a web server and not an application server.  Suggestions for those were to remove files from the `c:\windows\temp` folder or from the `%TEMP%` folder.  Then another was to run the Disk Cleanup Utility and then reboot the server.  None of this has helped.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

My environment:

- Server is Windows 2012R2 Server
- .NET Framework: 4.5

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.

Comment: Do you have the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

If the app is running under a specific user, make sure you also clear out the user temp folder. For example, make sure you clear out all items in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` where `<username>` is the user the application is running under.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out the %TEMP% folder on the box the app is hosted, which for me was 'C:\windows\temp'.

You can do this from the command prompt:

```
c:\Windows\Temp>del c:\Windows\Temp\*.*
c:\Windows\Temp\*.*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
```

Apparently, if there are too many files in the folder .NET is not able to serve web-pages through IIS.

See post about the issue [here](http://code-smart.org.uk/fixes/error-failed-to-compile-both-on-net-4-5-and-on-net-4-0-4-5-exception-system-io-ioexception-the-file-exists/)